# Data property no longer reactive after doing simple re-assignment?

Tags: vue.js

I have a data property called `current_room` where initially it has an empty object `{}`.

I have a component that will receive `current_room` as a "prop".

In the parent component, in the `mounted()` hook, re-assignment takes place: `this.current_room = new_room`

In the child component, the `current_room` prop appears to be... an empty object. In the parent component, it's not an empty object, it has the data I expect to see.

What would be the proper way to make this work? It seems as though simple re-assignment doesn't work in this case, that once I define a property on the data object... and that property is an object... I have to add/remove properties to the object, rather than just wholesale re-assigning a new object to that data property.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Blaine Lafreniere, David is right – we need to see what you've tried. You can use [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/vk64bzjh/15/) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just a simple mistake somewhere in your code. Because following to your question - it should work, furthermore I created a simple example where I defined components and functionality as you've described - and it works. I will provide async example to make you sure for 100 percents.

Here is the working example:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <CurrentRoom :room="current_room" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CurrentRoom from './components/CurrentRoom.vue'

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    CurrentRoom
  },
  data () {
    return {
      current_room: {}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.current_room = {
        door: true,
        windowsCount: 2,
        wallColor: 'white',
        members: [
          {
            name: 'Heisenberg',
            age: 46
          },
          {
            name: 'Pinkman',
            age: 26
          }
        ]
      }
    }, 2000)
  }
};
</script>
```

CurrentRoom.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    Current room is: <br>
    <pre>{{ room }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CurrentRoom',
    props: {
      room: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {}
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Codesandbox demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-banach-clyz4

And for the end, following to your question:

`... What would be the proper way to make this work? ...`

The answer is - 'Please, compare your code with provided example'